# Mask not displayed in OpenCV camera preview

Tags: java, c++, opencv, android

I want to make a simple Android app which put a mask on a detected face with OpenCV such as this example :

[Mask on face detection tutorial](http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2013/11/putting-mask-on-face-using-opencv.html)

I translate the C++ into Java for my app.The mask is well resized and the white part eliminated (I displayed the result for testing in an ImageView on the Preview) but the mask never appear on the detected face int the green rectangle :

[Screenshot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDRH6.jpg)

My code :

```
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
             [...]

    for( int i = 0; i < facesArray.length; i++)
        min_face_size = facesArray[0].width*0.7;
        max_face_size = facesArray[0].width*1.5;
        Point center=new Point (facesArray[i].x + facesArray[i].width/2, facesArray[i].y + facesArray[i].height/2);
        mRgba=putMask(mRgba,center, new Size(facesArray[i].width, facesArray[i].height));
    }
    return mRgba;
}

Mat putMask(Mat src, Point center, Size face_size)
{

    //mask : loaded mask image
    Mat mask1 = new Mat(); //resized mask
    src1 = new Mat(); //ROI
    m = new Mat();

    Imgproc.resize(mask ,mask1,face_size);

    // ROI selection
    roi = new Rect((int) (center.x - face_size.width/2), (int) (center.y - face_size.height/2),(int) face_size.width, (int) face_size.height);
    //Rect roi = new Rect(100, 100, (int) face_size.width, (int) face_size.height);
    src.submat(roi).copyTo(src1);


    // to make the white region transparent
    Mat mask2 = new Mat(); //greymask
    m1= new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mask1,mask2, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Imgproc.threshold(mask2,mask2,230,255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);

    ArrayList<Mat> maskChannels = new ArrayList<>(3);
    ArrayList<Mat> result_mask = new ArrayList<>(3);
    result_mask.add(new Mat());
    result_mask.add(new Mat());
    result_mask.add(new Mat());

    Core.split(mask1, maskChannels);

    Log.e(TAG, "MASK maskChannels :"+maskChannels.get(0).size());
    Log.e(TAG, "MASK mask2 :"+mask2.size());

    Core.bitwise_and(maskChannels.get(0),mask2, result_mask.get(0));
    Core.bitwise_and(maskChannels.get(1),mask2, result_mask.get(1));
    Core.bitwise_and(maskChannels.get(2),mask2, result_mask.get(2));
    Core.merge(result_mask, m);        


    Core.subtract(mask2, new Scalar(255), mask2);

    ArrayList<Mat> srcChannels = new ArrayList<>(3);
    Core.split(src1, srcChannels);
    Core.bitwise_and(srcChannels.get(0),mask2, result_mask.get(0));
    Core.bitwise_and(srcChannels.get(1),mask2, result_mask.get(1));
    Core.bitwise_and(srcChannels.get(2),mask2, result_mask.get(2));
    Core.merge(result_mask,m1);        


    Core.addWeighted(m,1,m1,1,0,m1);    

    m1.copyTo(src.submat(roi));

    return src;
}
```

==============

Thanks to @hariprasad :) here the working code :

```
 onCreate(){
          [...]
                try {
                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "1-alpha.png");

                    mask = Imgcodecs.imread(file.getPath(), -1);

                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }


Mat putMask(Mat src, Point center, Size face_size)
{

    //mask : masque chargé depuis l'image
    Mat mask_resized = new Mat(); //masque resizé
    src_roi = new Mat(); //ROI du visage croppé depuis la preview
    roi_gray = new Mat();


    Imgproc.resize(mask ,mask_resized,face_size);

    // ROI selection
    roi = new Rect((int) (center.x - face_size.width/2), (int) (center.y - face_size.height/2),(int) face_size.width, (int) face_size.height);
    //Rect roi = new Rect(10, 10, (int) face_size.width, (int) face_size.height);

    src.submat(roi).copyTo(src_roi);

    Log.e(TAG, "MASK SRC1 :"+ src_roi.size());

    // to make the white region transparent
    Mat mask_grey = new Mat(); //greymask
    roi_rgb = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mask_resized,mask_grey, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY);
    Imgproc.threshold(mask_grey,mask_grey,230,255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);

    ArrayList<Mat> maskChannels = new ArrayList<>(4);
    ArrayList<Mat> result_mask = new ArrayList<>(4);
    result_mask.add(new Mat());
    result_mask.add(new Mat());
    result_mask.add(new Mat());
    result_mask.add(new Mat());

    Core.split(mask_resized, maskChannels);

    Core.bitwise_and(maskChannels.get(0),mask_grey, result_mask.get(0));
    Core.bitwise_and(maskChannels.get(1),mask_grey, result_mask.get(1));
    Core.bitwise_and(maskChannels.get(2),mask_grey, result_mask.get(2));
    Core.bitwise_and(maskChannels.get(3),mask_grey, result_mask.get(3));

    Core.merge(result_mask, roi_gray);        

    Core.bitwise_not(mask_grey,mask_grey);

    ArrayList<Mat> srcChannels = new ArrayList<>(4);
    Core.split(src_roi, srcChannels);
    Core.bitwise_and(srcChannels.get(0),mask_grey, result_mask.get(0));
    Core.bitwise_and(srcChannels.get(1),mask_grey, result_mask.get(1));
    Core.bitwise_and(srcChannels.get(2),mask_grey, result_mask.get(2));
    Core.bitwise_and(srcChannels.get(3),mask_grey, result_mask.get(3));

    Core.merge(result_mask, roi_rgb);          

    Core.addWeighted(roi_gray,1, roi_rgb,1,0, roi_rgb); 

    roi_rgb.copyTo(new Mat(src,roi));

    return src;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the complete code for reference? I also have to implement the same Functionality.

Comment: No I'm sorry, it's for a company work, but I think the working code I gave is quite complete, you have the camera code in "onCameraFrame" (openCV framework) and the calculation. The rest is pretty much the basic OpenCV Android camera sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`src.submat(roi)` is not equalent to `src(roi)` in c++.Because in c++ `src(roi)` actually modifying the `src` data matrix in the roi area but in java `submat` is making clone of the roi of src.So any changes done to roi will not effect src that is why you got nothing in camera preview.
to make it correct you need to use constructor like c++
i.e use

```
m1.copyTo(new Mat(src,roi));
```

instead of

```
 m1.copyTo(src.submat(roi));
```

Comment: I change to "m1.copyTo(new Mat(src,roi));" but the result is still the same... I've also tried to change "src.submat(roi).copyTo(src1);" to "src1 = new Mat(src, roi);" but same result. I still don't understand why the ROI in the preview camera is not modified

Comment: you don't have to change "src.submat(roi).copyTo(src1)";as in c++ version also they are making copy here.there may be other problems in your code. Are you sure about this ? 255-mask2  in c++ equal to Core.subtract(mask2, new Scalar(255), mask2); I think the operands should be reverse i.e Core.subtract(new Scalar(255), mask2,mask2);

Comment: I'm not sure at all, but there isn't a Core.subtract(Scalar, Mat, Mat) method in the Java SDK, so I didn't know how to write mask2=255-mask2....

Comment: if it is not present then try core.invert

Comment: It throws an error : error: (-215) type == CV_32F || type == CV_64F in function double cv::invert(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int)    when I write Core.invert(mask2, mask2);

Comment: ok i never try invert so dont know about exception.please try this bitwise_not ( src, dst ); this should work.