# Detect face and apply a mask on it with openCV

Tags: android, opencv, real-time, face-detection, cascade-classifier

UPDATE: [here](http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2013/11/putting-mask-on-face-using-opencv.html) is opencv c++ sample and shows exactly what I want to do. Only thing is I need it with java.

I have been working on a real-time Android application which detects face with front camera and add a mask on a detected face. So far face detection is working well with cascade classifier.

I am drawing rectangles around face and circles for eyes:

```
 Rect[] facesArray = faces.toArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < facesArray.length; i++)
    {
        Imgproc.rectangle(mRgba, facesArray[i].tl(), facesArray[i].br(), FACE_RECT_COLOR, 3);

        xCenter = (facesArray[i].x + facesArray[i].width + facesArray[i].x) / 2;
        yCenter = (facesArray[i].y + facesArray[i].y + facesArray[i].height) / 2;
        Point center = new Point(xCenter, yCenter);
        Imgproc.circle(mRgba, center, 10, new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255), 3);

    }
```

My question is, how to apply an image on detected face and show it at real time. (e.g. sunglasses, hat, moustache, and a funny animal face)

If anyone could give a tip or tell me some key points, I would be so grateful.

[This](http://[https://github.com/Macadamian/MonkeyCam]) is a good example what I expect from my application. I have examined the code though but couldn't understand.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to "apply" an image on the captured image or on the face in real-time?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43964740/5799975) might help you get started (C++ code).

Comment: I want to apply an image on the face in real-time like snapchat effects. @RickM.

Answer (score 1):

You have to extract the landmarks of the face (a good library is http://dlib.net/).

[image]

For this task it's not really necessary to use the Haar Cascade Classifier to detect the face.

But it could help if you pass just a portion of your image (the section with only the face) to the algorithm that calculates the landmarks. In this case, with less data to compute, the algorithm should be faster. But remember to re-map the points to the original coordinate reference system of the full image.

Once that you had obtained this points you can easily overlap the image you need on the various frames captured from your camera.

Comment: I just want to attach a simple mask (no need to cover all face region). For example, attaching a sunglasses at the same position with the eye points I already have. Is it possible to do that without finding landmarks?

Comment: Yes. For example the openCV's Haar Cascade Classifier returns a Rect. You can use the Rect coordinates to draw what you want on the original image. It's less accurate (e.g. for the eyes you just know a region that contains them, and then calculate more or less the centre) than the face landmarks. For you goal may be enough.

Comment: @wlrs if you implemented this code please guide me some link. Coz i have same requirement as yours.

Comment: @PujaSingh see my answer. If any question I can explain detaills.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38749867/mask-not-displayed-in-opencv-camera-preview) is a working code for me for putting mask.

Thanks to @paul_poveda and @hariprasad

this is the method:

```
Mat putMask(Mat src, Point center, Size face_size){

//mask : masque chargé depuis l'image
Mat mask_resized = new Mat(); //masque resizé
src_roi = new Mat(); //ROI du visage croppé depuis la preview
roi_gray = new Mat();


Imgproc.resize(mask ,mask_resized,face_size);

// ROI selection
roi = new Rect((int) (center.x - face_size.width/2), (int) (center.y - face_size.height/2),(int) face_size.width, (int) face_size.height);
//Rect roi = new Rect(10, 10, (int) face_size.width, (int) face_size.height);

src.submat(roi).copyTo(src_roi);

Log.e(TAG, "MASK SRC1 :"+ src_roi.size());

// to make the white region transparent
Mat mask_grey = new Mat(); //greymask
roi_rgb = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(mask_resized,mask_grey, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY);
Imgproc.threshold(mask_grey,mask_grey,230,255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);

ArrayList<Mat> maskChannels = new ArrayList<>(4);
ArrayList<Mat> result_mask = new ArrayList<>(4);
result_mask.add(new Mat());
result_mask.add(new Mat());
result_mask.add(new Mat());
result_mask.add(new Mat());

Core.split(mask_resized, maskChannels);

Core.bitwise_and(maskChannels.get(0),mask_grey, result_mask.get(0));
Core.bitwise_and(maskChannels.get(1),mask_grey, result_mask.get(1));
Core.bitwise_and(maskChannels.get(2),mask_grey, result_mask.get(2));
Core.bitwise_and(maskChannels.get(3),mask_grey, result_mask.get(3));

Core.merge(result_mask, roi_gray);        

Core.bitwise_not(mask_grey,mask_grey);

ArrayList<Mat> srcChannels = new ArrayList<>(4);
Core.split(src_roi, srcChannels);
Core.bitwise_and(srcChannels.get(0),mask_grey, result_mask.get(0));
Core.bitwise_and(srcChannels.get(1),mask_grey, result_mask.get(1));
Core.bitwise_and(srcChannels.get(2),mask_grey, result_mask.get(2));
Core.bitwise_and(srcChannels.get(3),mask_grey, result_mask.get(3));

Core.merge(result_mask, roi_rgb);          

Core.addWeighted(roi_gray,1, roi_rgb,1,0, roi_rgb); 

roi_rgb.copyTo(new Mat(src,roi));

return src;}
```